# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable, como resolver? PySide2 QTableView

Tags: python, pyside

Estou fazendo o código para visualizar minha tabela sqlite3 na QTableView, mas ao botar para visualizar a tabela, na hora de rodar o código, surgiu esse erro citado, mas não consegui encontrar como resolve-lo...

Segue o código para buscar na tabela criada:

```
def consulta_nutri():
bank = Bank()


c = bank.conn.cursor()
n = 'SELECT * FROM nutricionistas'

c.execute(n)

resultados = c.fetchall()

num_colunas = len(c.description)
nome_colunas = [i[0] for  i in c.description]

dados = (resultados, nome_colunas)

return dados
```

Segue o código de visualizar a tabela no frame:

```
        dados = b.consulta_nutri
        self.modelo = CustomTableModel(dados)

        self.tabela = QTableView(self.frm_relatorio)
        self.tabela.setGeometry(0, 0, 630, 600)
        self.tabela.setModel(self.modelo)
```

Segue o código:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor


class CustomTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)

        self.meus_dados = data[0]
        self.minhas_colunas = data[1]

        self.load_data(self.meus_dados)

    def load_data(self, dados):
        self.numero_linhas = len(dados)
        self.numero_colunas = len(dados[0])

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex):
        return self.numero_linhas

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex):
        return self.numero_colunas

    def HeaderData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.minhas_colunas[section].upper()
        else:
            return section


    def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.meus_dados[row][column]
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignLeft
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QColor(Qt.white)

        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi achado, a função consulta_nutri() não estava dentro da classe do banco de dados.